# Installing Raspberry Pi Desktop on VM--small resolution

Tags: raspberry-pi-desktop

I installed Raspberry Pi Desktop on a VM on Windows, and am intrigued. However, I cannot find where/how to enlarge the display ("screen") resolution. Is is very small, and makes it difficult to do anything.

Also, the VM guest mouse is not always completely synchronized with my mouse, but maybe that is what I get for using a virtual machine. Can anyone give some beginner tips/resources?

Comment: Can't you just use normal debian with your vm? https://www.debian.org/

Comment: Right, I could. I had no real reason for this, but just wondered what I was doing wrong...

Comment: @derz00 — You're running [Pixel-x86](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/pixel-pc-mac/) in a VM?

Comment: @yeti it is the ISO at this link https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-desktop/ what's the difference between this and Pixel?

Comment: @derz00 – That's probably just an updated version of the brew formerly known as Pixel-x86. Maybe `$SOMEONE` has complained about the name "Pixel" and now it has to be named differently.

Answer (score 3):

In VirtualBox, you need to install the Guest Additions before it will recognized any other resolutions.

1. In VirtualBox, choose **Insert Guest Additions CD image...** from the Devices menu.
2. Next, you'll need to install the Guest Additions in a Terminal window.

   ```
   sudo sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxGuestAdditions.run
   ```
3. Reboot.
4. After rebooting, open a new Terminal and use the following command.

   ```
   lxrandr
   ```
5. Choose your preferred resolution and enjoy!.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ sudo leafpad /etc/default/grub
```

Change the line

```
''#GRUB_GFXMODE=800x600''
```

to for example:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080
```

Save the file

```
$ sudo update-grub

$ sudo reboot
```

This worked for me.

Comment: This will not work on RPI. It doesn't even use GRUB bootloader...

Comment: @71GA The OP is not asking about "on RPI", they are asking about Raspberry Pi [Desktop](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/raspberry-pi-desktop/) on a VM. GRUB *is* used for that.